# updating plist in ipad app

Tags: ipad

I have made an app that uses plists. What I want to do now is to be able to push plists as updates so that users can just download them and they get added to the current plist in the app. If someone could shed light on how I can implement this, I would be grateful.

Comment: [NSURL Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: could you please elaborate on what I need to do

Comment: @userXXXX you have to understand how networking in iOS works, after having accomplished that, you'll be able to achieve your goal without problems.